# Dyld Error Message: Symbol not found: _kCLErrorUserInfoAlternateRegionKey

Tags: ios

App(Xcode8 build) crashed when it launch on iOS7.0.x, but it's fine on iOS7.1+.

The CoreLocation.framework is optional in "Linked Frameworks And Libraries"

`Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _kCLErrorUserInfoAlternateRegionKey
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Applications/F412EBCB-BFC5-4BB8-9AB4-17EE5D7F02E6/xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
 in /private/var/mobile/Applications/F412EBCB-BFC5-4BB8-9AB4-17EE5D7F02E6/xxx.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib
  Dyld Version: 324`

Comment: We found Swift3+ObjC could have caused the problem, Swift2.3+ObjC work fine